# Making CMake choose static linkage when possible?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I'm working on a project that's link against SOCI, which comes as both static and dynamic libraries.  I'd like CMake to choose the static version when available, and dynamic otherwise.  Is there a reasonable way to do this in CMake?  I've come up with nothing looking through the docs so far.

Comment: ...and don't forget that besides being a gcc specific solution, gcc will fail to link if you pass -static but not **all** libraries provided for linkage are static - which can easily happen if you use the FindXXXX.cmake modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to add CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-static

Comment: However, don't forget it is GCC specific solution. Though, OP doesn't specify what compiler/linker/system is under consideration.