# Can't statically link boost libraries with cmake

Tags: boost, cmake

I've boost signals library, builded with:

```
./b2 address-model=32 link=static --build-type=complete --with-signals --layout=tagged
```

simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/signal.hpp"

void onSignal() {
 std::cout << "Hello from slot" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  boost::signal<void()> sig;
  sig.connect(&onSignal);
  sig();
 return 0;
}
```

CmakeLists.txt:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32 -static")
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
include_directories(/home/koshchiy/dev/boost/boost_1_51_0)
link_directories(/home/koshchiy/dev/boost/boost_1_51_0/stage)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libboost_signals-mt-s.a)
```

It builds without errors, but while runnig, I'm got:

```
bash: ./test: No such file or directory
```

seems to be, that cmake produces dynamic linking instead of static:

```
koshchiy@koshchiy-lin-NB:~/dev/projects/test/test-build-release$ ldd test
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf778b000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf768e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf74e7000)
libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf74bc000)
/usr/lib/libc.so.1 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf778c000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf749e000)
```

Building without cmake seems to be ok:

```
g++ -static main.cpp -o test -I... -l...
```

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 x64 and g++-4.7 compiler.

Comment: If you get "No such file or directory" when executing ./test I believe you are either in the wrong path or it did not build. Could ~/dev/projects/test/test-build-release/test have been created earlier?

Answer (score 3):

Your manual build is done without the `-m32` flag that you are using in the CMakeLists.txt in the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS .

Thus the build with cmake results in a 32-bit executable, which fails to work with "No such file" even though the file exists, because you're missing the binary support for 32-bits on your system.

Either remove the `-m32` of your CMakeFiles.txt or try to install the gcc-multilib support for your system and your gcc-version.

If you want to force static linking to your cmake-build check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762057/cmake-how-to-produce-binaries-as-static-as-possible) can help you.