# Linking with a static library through CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, linker, cmake, static-linking

I am trying to use cmake to build my project. I want to link against libpng which is present in my system. This is my code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(main)

file(GLOB SOURCES *.c)
add_executable(sphstego ${SOURCES})

find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(main ${PNG_LIBRARY})

message(STATUS "PNG_LIBRARY: " ${PNG_LIBRARY}) # correct path to so file
```

My problem is that I want to link statically rather than dynamically. Furthermore, and although the variable set as PNG_LIBRARY is correctly set to ***/usr/local/lib/libpng.so***, I get an error message when running my executable:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991225/cmake-and-static-linking

Comment: Lots of information on linking internal and external libraies statically here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762057/cmake-how-to-produce-binaries-as-static-as-possible