# Deplying a C++ application on Linux- linking everything statically to simplify deployment?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile, build

I am building a C++ project from Github and want to deploy the code to a remote Linux machine. This is all new to me.

The project has a main.cpp, which includes the various headers/sources like a library.

The CMake outputs an executable (to represent main.cpp) AND a separate static library. The project also uses OpenSSL, which I have linked statically.

1. I presume the OpenSSL functions are included within the static library? So when I deploy, I don't need to copy-over or install any OpenSSL on the remote machine?
2. Is it possible to modify the CMake so the application and the library are merged in to one file?

I am trying to make deployment as simple as copying over a single file, if this is possible.

Any additional advice/references are most-welcome.

UPDATE the CMake script:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake;${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

project(helloworld C CXX)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

set (BUILD_MAIN TRUE)
set (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS FALSE)
set (OPENSSL_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

set( HELLOWORLD_HEADERS    helloworld/File1.h       helloworld/File2.h    )
set( HELLOWORLD_SOURCES    helloworld/File1.cpp     helloworld/File2.cpp  )

# Static library
add_library( helloworld  ${HELLOWORLD_SOURCES}    ${HELLOWORLD_HEADERS}   )

# Rapidjson
include_directories(/tmp/rapidjson/include/)


# OpenSSL
if (NOT OPENSSL_FOUND)
  find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
endif()

add_definitions(${OPENSSL_DEFINITIONS})

target_include_directories(helloworld PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}>)
target_link_libraries(helloworld PRIVATE ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})

set( HELLOWORLD_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

include(GNUInstallDirs)

target_include_directories(helloworld PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${HELLOWORLD_INCLUDE_DIRS}/>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/helloworld>
)

set_target_properties(helloworld PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${HELLOWORLD_HEADERS}")

add_library(helloworld::helloworld ALIAS helloworld)

option(HELLOWORLD_INSTALL "Install HelloWorld" TRUE)

if (HELLOWORLD_INSTALL)
  install(TARGETS helloworld
          EXPORT helloworld
          ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
          PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/helloworld/
  )

  configure_file("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/helloworld-config.cmake.in" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld-config.cmake" @ONLY)
  install(FILES "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld-config.cmake" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/helloworld")
  
  install(EXPORT helloworld
          FILE helloworld-targets.cmake
          NAMESPACE helloworld::
          DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/helloworld
  )
endif()


if (BUILD_MAIN) 
  add_executable(main main.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(main helloworld) 
endif()
```

Comment: I think you are confused on what static libraries are and do. Deploying them next to a binary does nothing. They have to be linked into a binary to work. Did you mean a dynamic library? (.so)

Comment: Could you please provide the GitHub repository link?

Comment: @Botje Ahhhhh, do you mean only a dynamic library is required to co-exist alongside the executable and the fact i linked statically means the code is already contained within the executable? If I am correct, what is the point of outputting a static library separately?

Comment: @Fureeish I'll paste the CMake script in to my question but I need a bit of time. I will message again once i've done it.

Comment: @Fureeish CMake script added

Comment: @mezamorphic the point of static library file creating in public era, for reusing this library in another projects and exe

Comment: @sorosh_sabz Thank you so much. Which line is outputting the library and can i just remove the line?

Comment: Why do you want to remove line? your library is static linked and you do not need to copy library alongside of your binary

Comment: If you want to remove installation of the library, then delete the whole branch `if (HELLOWORLD_INSTALL)`, alongside with the definition of the option `HELLOWORLD_INSTALL`.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz Understood but then what's the point of outputting it each time?

Comment: Intrigued what "*Deplying*" in the Title might mean, nearly 1 year after this Qt was asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very helpful to make URL of your GitHub's project, but I write some public notes about that

In generally in CMake for static linking your library to your executable, you can write simple like below (from [official CMake example](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#id16))

```
add_library(archive archive.cpp zip.cpp lzma.cpp)
add_executable(zipapp zipapp.cpp)
target_link_libraries(zipapp archive)
```

In above example your executable file is just work without needing `.a` library file and you can simple copy single file.

if you want to make all of thing static, you make sure all dependencies make static link to your project, like [CMake: how to produce binaries "as static as possible"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3762057/1539100)

if you want to prevent library creation, Probably in your CMake file, you can find [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) command, and [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) command. you can remove `add_library` command and add all sources to `add_executable` command.

for example `add_executable(a.out main.cpp lib.cpp)`

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I've just added the CMake script to my question.

Comment: @mezamorphic So, I think your cmake script probably does not problem, and you can copy main single executable file to another location without need to copy your library